# Close file after fs.readFile, nulling

Tags: node.js, fs

Just try nodejs a few days.
Should i close somehow files after `fs.readFile()` ? And if yes how?
Should i null or something used and needless variables for better perfomance and memory safe?

Thanks.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

to close a file descriptor use this call

```
fs.close(fd, callback)
```

however since you're using `fs.readFile` which reads the entire file - it deals with opening and closing file for you, so you don't need to close anything

Comment: Then why does the documentation say _Note: Specified file descriptors will not be closed automatically._?

Comment: (I'm guessing that means "If you specify a file descriptor, instead of specifying a file path string, as the first argument.)

Comment: It now states: "Note: If a file descriptor is specified as the file, it will not be closed automatically."